Swagger UI freeze when response is too large around 2mb
I have added OpenAPI doc to my Function app project using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi, but the swagger/ui freeze when the response is too large, around 2mb. Is there anything I can do about it?
My function that returns large response:
[Function("GetBookableResources")]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetBookableResources", tags: new[] { "Bookable Resource" }, Summary = "Get Bookable Resources", Description = "", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
[OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(BookableResourcesRequestBody),Description = "JSON request body", Required = true)]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(List<BookableResourcesResponse>), Summary = "The response", Description = "This returns the response")]
public IActionResult GetBookableResources([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req, [FromBody] BookableResourcesRequestBody reqBody)
{
    try
    {   
        var bookableResources = _bookableResourceService.GetBookableResources(reqBody);

        return new OkObjectResult(bookableResources);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Get Bookable resources error: {ex.Message}");
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex.Message);
    }
}

Program.cs:
services.AddSingleton<IOpenApiConfigurationOptions>(_ =>
{
    var options = new OpenApiConfigurationOptions()
    {
        Info = new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Version = "1.0.0",
            Title = "API",
            Description = "This is API."
        },
        Servers = DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions.GetHostNames(),
        OpenApiVersion = OpenApiVersionType.V3,
        IncludeRequestingHostName = true,
        ForceHttps = false,
        ForceHttp = false
    };

    return options;
});


It's a known issue with Swagger UI and large responses.
Does the .NET library that you use have a configuration option to disable syntax highlighting in Swagger UI, i.e. set its syntaxHighlight.activated to false? If yes, it might help improve performance.
Also consider implementing pagination for your "get list of items" endpoints and limiting data retrieval to a maximum of N items at a time (e.g. 100). This will help improve both your server performance and the developer experience for your API consumers.

I think you are working with base64 string right because over than 2 MB can be occurred with base64 strings ?
If it is you can return as a file instead of string. Swagger supports it!
For example-->
return File(yourMemoryStreamData, ContentTypes.png, "image.png");


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I lived same situation with base64 strings sometimes it crashes completely. With the help of this return type it took control of the way of returning. It helped me and I wanted to suggest it to this person.
